# Visio Zoom functionality is not properly working at 100% level

Tags: c#, visio

I am building an application in C#, which uses Microsoft visio feature's for drawing the objects/shapes.(I am using Microsoft VISIO - 2010)

In which i am using the zoom functionality provided by visio. The behavior is very odd while zooming between at 100% to other values. Say, i open visio canvas (at this point zoom value is at 75%) draw any shape at any extreme corner of the canvas. Now, I increased the zoom value to 100%, horizontal and vertical scroll bar comes to the center. At this point I again did zoom back to 75%, the object is not visible. That means when zooming in to 100% or zooming out to 100% the page automatically centers itself. But, I want to retain the position of scroll bar to some extent.

The problem is only coming for 100% zoom, it works fine for all other values.

### Below is the Sample Code:

```
zoomComboBox.SelectedItem is 100.
private AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.AxDrawingControl canvas;
canvas.Window.Zoom = Convert.ToDouble(zoomComboBox.SelectedItem)/100;
```

can anyone help me out on this?

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late answer to this question, but this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2f7292ba-f670-4df8-9bdc-75b1c49f3825/whats-wrong-with-visio-2010?forum=visiogeneral)  has some interesting discussion on zoom issues in Visio, and specifically includes code to fix the usual zoom issue where simply trying to change the zoom in the ui doesn't behave as expected.